# XRDP stopped working!

Tags: 14.04, xrdp

All of a sudden when I try to login I get this message:

```
xrdp_mm_processes_login:login failed
```

Anyone know how to fix this?
It's been working for months without any issues.. Then tonight I had a power outage and now this morning this happens..

Using Ubuntu Desktop 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic troubleshooting would be...

- restart xrdp service ?
- restart the computer completely ?

If this is still failing, maybe you have a orphaned "X session". To check this, perform the following actions

in terminal console, type the following

- **cd /tmp/.X11-unix**
- ls -l

if you see a session associated with your name, delete that session
Restart xrdp and try again

If this is not fixing your issue, then try the following, 
in Terminal console, type 
vncserver

if you have a message like

**Warning: Head-Node:1 is taken because of /tmp/.X11-unix/X1**

**Remove this file....**

you have an orphaned X session and you need to delete the file....
Say yes on the screen...

Hope this help 
Till next time 
See ya